# How to create a hierarchy of pages?

Tags: navigation

Just started using sharepoint and it seems quite user friendly. For example, on the left bar, there is a "[+ Add new page" link. It then presents a dialog that lets me name my name page. The problem is how to a setup a hierarchy of pages? So in my new page "Sales", how do I create a sub page called "Q1", a page called "Q2"? And then have it accessible within "Sales"? If I press the new page again, it just creates it at the top level under "Site pages".

Answer (score 7):

Pages are stored within Libraries, and Libraries are stored within Sites.

This hierarchy is strict, and you cannot store Libraries within Libraries, or Pages directly in Sites.

Therefore, you need to decide if you only want to infer a hierarchy of pages via visible links within the page content, or if you need to enforce a strict hierarchy using multiple sub-websites.

So, an example hierarchy using sites could look like this (Note that `Pages` is a library):

```
Top-Level Site
 - Pages
   - Sales
 - Sub Site 1
    - Pages
      - Q1
 - Sub Site 2
    - Pages
      - Q2
 - Sub Site 3
    - Pages
      - Q3
```

Of course this might be overkill, so if you just had a flat page hierarchy, looking like this:

```
Top-Level Site
 - Pages
   - Sales
     - Q1
     - Q2
     - Q3
```

And you just directly have links to Q1, Q2 and Q3 form within Sales, and back up.

The final alternative is to have one website but with multiple libraries, like this:

```
Top-Level Site
 - Sales Pages
 - Q1 Pages
 - Q2 Pages
 - Q3 Pages
 - Q4 Pages
```

Note that this only works for 'Wiki Libraries' and not 'Publishing Portals'. The easy way to see which kind of site you're working with is whether or not hte homepage has 'Pages' in the URL, or if it has 'SitePages'. If it has the latter, you're working with a Wiki based site, and you can have multiple Wiki libraries in a site. But with a Publishing Portal, you can only have one 'Pages' library per sub web site.

*Note: the last paragraph applies to SharePoint 2010*

Comment: What if you needed multiple level? Say, under Q1, there is TeamA and TeamB? Which approach is the easiest? And also, could you please provide the exact steps on what to click? Thank you!!

Comment: If you have permissions, then from the Site Actions menu you should see 'More Options'. From here, you can pick a site template. The most common choices are Team Sites or Publishing Portals. If you have a Publishing Site, the only option is a Publishing Portal, otherwise you can go for a Team Site. This will let you create a hierarchy of sites.

Comment: Again, this might be overkill, so you may even create a hierarchy of Folders within your Pages library. In 'View All Site Content' you can navigate to Site Pages, and create Folders in which to place pages.

Comment: James, sorry but I'm still completely lost. I can tell you that the site we have is a Team Site. I want to create many levels of pages. Where a user can navigate down into sub pages, and then back up. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you go with OOTB SharePoint navigation: For creating hierarchy N levels deep(where N>1) , you will need to create N-1 subsites one under another. The pages come at Nth level.

- For 2 level hierarchy, you can create a subsite *Sales* and two pages *Q1* and *Q2* in any document library.
- For 3 level hierarchy, Create a subsite *Sales*,under that create subsite *Q1* and two pages *Q1results* and *Q1Profit* in it.

and so on...

If you don't want to go with subsites, create hierarchy in a XML and consume it with XMLSiteMapProvider.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong here, but with SharePoint 2010, creating a Wiki Page does not give the option of selecting the folder to save the page in.  It will always be created in the "Site Pages" folder.

Of course at some point we can move these pages to another library that contains a structure of folders.  The problem here is that the URL of these pages will change after the move.  Besides, it would be a cumbersome moving pages to their new locations every time they are created.